# How should one calculate the time derivative of accelerometer data (jerk) in real-time (Java)?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, timedelta, differentiation

I am trying to calculate the time-derivative of acceleration (jerk) from the streamed accelerometer data within the `onReceive()` looping Android method.

I assumed that, from one sensor update to the next, I could approximate this by simply calculating the delta acceleration (x, y, z) and the associated delta time. To ensure maximal accuracy, I used the `System.nanoTime()` method (and divided by 10e8).

Everything seemed happy, and jerk data was appearing, but I thought it wise to check that the sum of all `delta_time`s (`sumDeltaTime`) was close to the difference between `last_time` and `first_time`. To my surprise, the difference was several thousand times out. Even replacing `System.nanoTime()` with `System.currentTimeMillis()` (divided by 10e2) did not change this discrepency. Here is my code:

```
// calculate jerk (time derivative of acceleration)

accel_count++;

if (accel_count == 1) {
    first_time = new_time = System.nanoTime() / 10e8; // captures first time value (in seconds)
    newAccel[0] = accel[0]; // x
    newAccel[1] = accel[1]; // y
    newAccel[2] = accel[2]; // z
    } else {
    prev_time = new_time; // assigns previous time value
    new_time = System.nanoTime() / 10e8; // immediately updates to the new time value (in seconds)
    prevAccel[0] = newAccel[0]; // x
    prevAccel[1] = newAccel[1]; // y
    prevAccel[2] = newAccel[2]; // z
    // set up for next iteration
    newAccel[0] = accel[0]; // x
    newAccel[1] = accel[1]; // y
    newAccel[2] = accel[2]; // z
    }
float[] delta_accel; // difference in acceleration between consecutive sensor measurements
delta_accel = new float[] {
    (newAccel[0] - prevAccel[0]), // x
    (newAccel[1] - prevAccel[1]), // y
    (newAccel[2] - prevAccel[2])  // z
    };
double delta_time = (new_time - prev_time); // time difference between consecutive sensor measurements (in seconds)

float[] jerk;
jerk = new float[] {
    (float) (delta_accel[0] / delta_time), // x
    (float) (delta_accel[1] / delta_time), // y
    (float) (delta_accel[2] / delta_time)  // z
    };

total_time = new_time - first_time; // total time duration of entire recording (in seconds)
sumDeltaTime += delta_time; // testing sum of deltas
```

Can anybody see what I must be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: 10e2 == 100, 10e8 == 100000000, so your calculations are off by a factor of 10. Also, use `SensorEvent.timestamp`.

Comment: I tried 10e3 and 10e9 to begin with and, strangely, the total_time was not returning seconds. Try it; weird! Many thanks for the advice regarding SensorEvent.timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialize `prev_time` on the first pass (`accel_count == 1`), so it was probably 0 the first time you calculated `delta_time`. This made the first `delta_time` unusually large, because `new_time` is much larger than 0, just as `System.nanoTime()` is much larger than 0.

Comment: Yes! That did the trick - many thanks indeed! The total_time and sum of delta_times are now a perfect match :)   (I have upvoted but my vote won't show as my score isn't high enough)